# What is the use of extern in declaring constants?

Tags: objective-c

can please tell me what is the use of extern variable when declaring the constant variables in different file.

Comment: You mean the `extern` declaration? If so, it is the same as in C ;)

Comment: So is it possible to declare an local variable whose name is same as the external variable in the same file?

Comment: @prithviraj, yes it is. It will "overshadow" the global declaration.

Answer (score 5):

The `extern` keywords forces the compiler to treat the statement as a declaration rather than a definition. In other words, `extern`  prevents the compiler from reserving space for the variable. Thus, only the compilation unit which does not use `extern` provides a definition, while the others merely use the declaration, which is in keeping with the "one definition rule"; if each compilation unit were to reserve space independently for the same variable, it would result in a violation of the "one definition rule". Note that `extern` literally means that "the definition is provided externally (by a different compilation unit)".

Answer (score 1):

Just like C, extern keyword means that the symbol is defined in another object file that will be linked to this one in compilation phase.